# input from Keyboard into Array list of persons

Tags: java, arraylist, arrayobject

I want to accept input from user to populate an Array list of Person. for some reason. I can't get it to work. I can add an item into the list I have created below are my code for reference. in the SimplepersonDatabase class in switch function case 2:, I want to accept an an input of names, date of birth from the user and the program should automatically assign the   position number starting from

e.g

```
001. Damien Kluk September, 12.09.1975
002. James  Hunt January , 12.09.2000
```

I should be able to also delete a person and sort the list of Persons. here are what I have implemented so far.

```
public class Person { //Person.java
public String fn;
public String ln;
public Date dob;
public int id;

   public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String fn, String ln, Date dob, int id) {
        this.fn = fn;
        this.ln = ln;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

---

```
class List {//List.java

int MAX_LIST = 20;
Person[] persons;
int count;


public List() {
    persons = new Person[MAX_LIST];
    count=0;
}

public int numberOfPersons() {
    return count;
}

public void add(Person person) {
    checkUniqueId(person);
    if (count >= persons.length) {
        // Enlarge array
        persons = Arrays.copyOf(persons, persons.length + 100);
    }
    persons[count] = person;
    ++count;
}

private void checkUniqueId(Person person) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
       if (persons[i].id == person.id) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Already a person with id "
                + person.id);
       }
    }
}

public void remove(int personId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (persons[i].id == personId) {
            --count;
            persons[i] = persons[count];
            persons[count] = null;
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No person known with id "
        + personId);
}

}
```

---

```
public class SimplePersonDataBase { //SimplePersonDataBase.java



private static List list;
private static int nextPersonId;



public static void main(String[] args) {

    go();

}

public static void go() {

    List link = new List();

    TextIO.put("Welcome to the SimplePersonDatabase.\n");
    TextIO.putln();

    int option;
    do{

        TextIO.put("available options:\n1) list\n2) add\n3) remove\n4) sort\n5) find\n6) settings\n0) quit\nyour choice:");
        option = TextIO.getInt();

        switch(option){
        case 1:
            PersonFunctions.display();
            break;
        case 2:   // Should accept inputs from a user and update the Persons database
            TextIO.put("Firstname:");
            String fn = TextIO.getlnWord();
            TextIO.put("Lastname:");
            String ln = TextIO.getlnWord();
            Date date = DateFunctions.scanDate();
            int pos = link.count;
            Person item = new Person(fn,ln,date,pos);
            add(item);
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            TextIO.putln("sort by:\n1) Firstname\n2) Birth\nall other values: lastname");
            switch(TextIO.getInt()){
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            default :
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 0:
            TextIO.put("Thank you for using the SimplePersonDatabase.");
            break;
        case 99:
            break;
        default :
            TextIO.put("illegal option.");
            break;
        }

    }while(option !=0);




}

   public static boolean add(Person personadd) {
       personadd.id = nextPersonId;
       ++nextPersonId;
       list.add(personadd);
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922132/how-can-i-implement-an-array-linkedlist-of-type-personspersons

Comment: If this is homework, it _might_ make sense to implement your own List. If not, use [Java's ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: "I can't get it to work" isn't very descriptive. Can you show us the Exception you are getting? And please describe the exact behaviour you expect.

Comment: Note that: since you wish to delete objects from the list, you will face a logical error in the way you try to implement it with int nextPersonId. For example, if there are 10 ids and the person you wish to delete has the id 5, in the way you implemented, either 5 wont be used again at all, or you will do nextPersonId-1 which will result in a logical error(2 objects having the same ID when you add a new one). I would suggest you to generate some IDs add them in a queue, and enqueu/dequeu when you add/remove users.

Comment: Okay. The behavior I expect is adding users to the list and displaying them. Along with adding the users. I want to also delete object from the list. the person is should be automatically assigned for the new user that will be added to the list

Answer (score 0):

Your list is working well (I tried + or -)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

class Person { // Person.java
public String fn;
public String ln;
public Date dob;
public int id;

public Person() {
}

public Person(String fn, String ln, Date dob, int id) {
    this.fn = fn;
    this.ln = ln;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.id = id;
}
 }
```

the list

```
 public class MyList {

int MAX_LIST = 20;
Person[] persons;
int count;

public MyList() {
    persons = new Person[MAX_LIST];
    count = 0;
}

public int numberOfPersons() {
    return count;
}

public void add(Person person) {
    checkUniqueId(person);
    if (count >= persons.length) {
        // Enlarge array
        System.out.println("enlarging");
        persons = Arrays.copyOf(persons, persons.length + 100);
    }
    persons[count] = person;
    ++count;
}

private void checkUniqueId(Person person) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (persons[i].id == person.id) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Already a person with id "
                    + person.id);
        }
    }
}

public void remove(int personId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (persons[i].id == personId) {
            --count;
            persons[i] = persons[count];
            persons[count] = null;
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No person known with id "
            + personId);
}

public Person get(int i) {
    return persons[i];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyList list = new MyList();
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {

        list.add(new Person("fn"+i,"sn"+i,new Date(),i));
        System.out.println(list.get(i) + " " + list.count);
    }


}

}
```

the problem is in the "go" function, **why you are using link and then you add in list**?

Comment: you are assigning to person.id = link.count but link.count never changes....remove link varibale and use list.count

Comment: I tried that. but I cannot display the lists of persons. Can you have a look at my display function. Maybe its the problem or something else